# Find every combination of cells in a column where the sum is a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

If given a column of data in Excel, for example:

```
2
5
8
10
3
6
```

Is it possible to check the column to find every all combinations where they meet a specific criteria? In this example when and the sum of any combination of those values is equal to 8.

The values it should find would be

```
2
5
8
3
6
```

As 2+6, 5+3, 8 all equal 8

It's my understanding that I am basically asking to check the following

```
if 2 = 8 or
if 5 = 8 or
if 8 = 8 or
if 10 = 8 or
if 3 = 8 or
if 6 = 8 or
if 2+5 = 8 or
if 2+8 = 8 or
if 2+10 = 8 or
if 2+3 = 8 or
if 2+6 = 8 or
etc
```

I have only used simple numbers to try and give an example. I'm fairly certain this is not possible.

Comment: getting 404 error on that link.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.  You have to enter the values to match in column A and the results will show up in column B.  I was able to achive a two way match and a three way match. if you wan Can do it till 5 way match after it will become more complex.

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim RowNumber As Double
    Dim Temp1 As Double
    Dim Temp2 As Double
    Dim Temp3 As Double
    Dim Result As Double
    Dim MatchCount As Double

    'Value to be searched
    Result = Application.InputBox("Please insert a Number", "Combi Calculator", "", , , , , 1)        
    'get the last row
    RowNumber = Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    'set matchcount to
    MatchCount = 1

    'Two way match
    For Temp1 = 2 To RowNumber
        For Temp2 = 3 To RowNumber
            If Cells(Temp1, 2) = "" And Cells(Temp2, 2) = "" Then
                If Cells(Temp1, 1) + Cells(Temp2, 1) = Result Then
                    Cells(Temp1, 2) = MatchCount
                    Cells(Temp2, 2) = MatchCount

                    MatchCount = MatchCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Three way match
    For Temp1 = 2 To RowNumber
        For Temp2 = 3 To RowNumber
            For Temp3 = 4 To RowNumber
                If Cells(Temp1, 2) = "" And Cells(Temp2, 2) = "" And Cells(Temp3, 2) = "" And Temp1 <> Temp2 And Temp2 <> Temp3 And Temp1 <> Temp3 Then
                    If Cells(Temp1, 1) + Cells(Temp2, 1) + Cells(Temp3, 1) = Result Then
                        Cells(Temp1, 2) = MatchCount
                        Cells(Temp2, 2) = MatchCount
                        Cells(Temp3, 2) = MatchCount
                        MatchCount = MatchCount + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I am not sure how to send a excel file as an attachement as I am new to this page.

meanwhile let me reseach time topic a bit more.  This was always area I wanted to work in (i.e., logic).

Comment: Just tested and I think that would do the trick!

Is it possible to get it ask for the number to search (where the value is 8 at the moment)

The only other thing I noticed is using the values
4
    2 
    6 
    4 
    1 
    3 
    4


I would be expecting to see the pairs, 2+6, 1+3+4, 4+4, or am I asking too much?

Comment: Hi, I have now made the change so the tool will ask user to input the value and it will proceed only if a numeric value is inserted. The logic works in sequency. First it would check for two way match and then it would go for three way match.  It will be bit dificult to do it otherwise.    Sandesh :)

Comment: PS: I have made changes to my orginal answer

Answer (score 1):

A two-way match is very simple using `COUNTIF`. If your number range is in column A and you want to find two numbers in the range that sum to 72, enter this formula in B1 and copy it down to B20:

```excel
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$20,72-A1)
```